# Is there any 3rd party tools supports TFS 2013 Branch and Merge command?

Tags: delphi, version-control, tfs

Is there any 3rd party tools support TFS 2013 Branch and Merge command ?

Here are some context information:

1. Existing source code is Delphi, using Delphi 2007 (IDE), and we are redeveloping entire product to C# (LOC 2.7m+)
2. We do many **branches and merge**. (we need it)
3. Using SVN at this moment
4. Want to migrate TFS 2013
5. C# developers are using VS2013, therefore they has no problem with TFS 2013
6. Delphi developers are using **Delphi 2007** (CodeGear)

What I have searched:

1. Team Explorer: a good options. But It cannot be integrated into Delphi IDE.
2. SvnBridge (V4): Branch is not fully developed and unstable. Merge is not developed.
3. MSSCCI Provider + SourceConnexion: no branch and merge support.
4. TFS Power Tools: works well with Windows Explorer, but it does not provide branch and merge in its menu.
5. TFS+GIT: could be a option, but it will increase curve of learning for whole team, but it is still a option

Question:

Is there any other tools I can try to integrate TFS to Delphi, including **Branch and Merge** command?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need ide integration?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it would be great to have ide integration, but most important part is branch and merge functionality.

Comment: Well, doesn't TFS have that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, TFS provides that. But, you only be able to use it within either Visual Studio or Team Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have full command line support for both Windows and Linux. You have Team Explorer which is the APIbfor windows and Team Explorer everywhere which provides support for Eclipse and most eclipse derived IDE.

In both cases you also get native command line tools:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253088.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661

Advice: Move to Git in TFS and use whatever tools that you like.

Comment: Thank you @MrHinsh. That exactly what I am looking for. I just need to confirm there is not another way to do this, except to using TFS +GIT. We have decide to evaluate this approach now.